# Form Submit Javascript PHP not working, help please?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am having a hard time getting my form to work.

Can anyone take a look at this and tell me why nothing happens when I try it in a live environment? I managed to get the form to submit using "action" in the form tag whilst ditching the javascript altogether, with the PHP returning both Error and success depending on whether I filled out all fields and the email was successfully received.

However I want to use the javascript method so that I can prevent a page reload and use alert messages as this form will be used inside a packaged mobile app.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
    <form  method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
      <label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
      <input name="FirstName" type="text" id="FirstName">
      <label for="textfield2">Text Field:</label>
      <input name="LastName" type="text"  id="LastName">
      <label for="textfield3">Text Field:</label>
      <input name="Email" t ype="text"id="Email">
      <label for="textfield4">Text Field:</label>
      <input name="MessageText" type="text"  id="MessageText">

    <input type="button" onclick="submit()" value="submit contact"/>
   </form>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      event.preventDefault();
      $("form").submit(function(){
        $.post('http://************/requestform.php', {



        FirstName: $('#FirstName_input').val(),
        LastName: $('#LastName_input').val(),
        Email: $('#Email_input').val(),
        MessageText: $('#MessageText_input').val()



        }, function (html) {

            var response=html;


             if (response=="success") {
               alert("Message sent!"); 
            } else {


               alert("Sorry please fill all fields!"); 
            return false;
        }
       });

      });
    });
```

and the PHP part

```
    <?php


     $FirstName=$_POST["FirstName"];
     $LastName=$_POST["LastName"];
     $Email=$_POST["Email"];
     $MessageText=$_POST["MessageText"];
     $Headers = "From:" . $Email;


     if(
     $FirstName=="" ||
     $LastName=="" ||
     $Email=="" ||
     $MessageText==""
     ) {
         echo "Error";
     } else {
         mail("*******@gmail.com","mobile app message",$MessageText, $Headers);
         echo "success";
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: why you are calling submit function on button click...?? `onclick="submit()"`

Comment: The URL is to the same domain I assume? If not, you're likely running into violation of the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: Why do you even need a Form submit and preventdefault? Only `$.post` should work. If full refresh is what you want then why don't you do a regular submit with `<input type="submit"/>`

Comment: When I was using the regular method the browser would navigate away from the request page. I also needed a prevent default because each time the page loaded I would get the error message from the js because each field wasn't filled in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make an ajax call when user clicks the button. To do that assign a click handler to your button.

Try this:

```
<form  method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
    <label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
    <input name="FirstName" type="text" id="FirstName">
    <label for="textfield2">Text Field:</label>
    <input name="LastName" type="text"  id="LastName">
    <label for="textfield3">Text Field:</label>
    <input name="Email" type="text"id="Email">
    <label for="textfield4">Text Field:</label>
    <input name="MessageText" type="text"  id="MessageText">

    <input type="button" id="submitContactBtn" value="submit contact"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        // we will perform an AJAX call when user clicks the button
        $('#submitContactBtn').click(function(){

            $.post('http://************/requestform.php', {

            FirstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
            LastName: $('#LastName').val(),
            Email: $('#Email').val(),
            MessageText: $('#MessageText').val()        

            }, function(response){

                var result = responce.replace(/\s/g, ''); // clear all whitespaces, just in case

                if( result == 'success' ){
                    alert("Message sent!"); 
                } else {
                    alert("Sorry please fill all fields!"); 
                }

            });     

        });

    });

</script>
```

Please note that I've added id to your button:

```
<input type="button" id="submitContactBtn" value="submit contact"/>
```

Comment: Tried this also. I don't understand why this isn't working. I must be missing something really fundamental!

Comment: @OliverJ90 I reviewed the issue and made different code. Please try this

Comment: I really appreciate your time. This doesn't seem to work either though. I know the php script works but getting the javascript alerts to work is just not happening.

Comment: thanks for your help, I got this figured out eventually with $('input[type="button"][value="Send Request"]').click(function() {

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `$_GET` to access the variables.

Use `$_POST`.

So change:

```
$FirstName=$_GET["FirstName"];
$LastName=$_GET["LastName"];
$Email=$_GET["Email"];
```

to:

```
$FirstName=$_POST["FirstName"];
$LastName=$_POST["LastName"];
$Email=$_POST["Email"];
```

**UPDATE:**

Change:

```
    FirstName: $('#FirstName_input').val(),
    LastName: $('#LastName_input').val(),
    Email: $('#Email_input').val(),
    MessageText: $('#MessageText_input').val()
```

To:

```
    FirstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
    LastName: $('#LastName').val(),
    Email: $('#Email').val(),
    MessageText: $('#MessageText').val()
```

Why do you add `_input`to the input id?

**UPDATE 2**

Edit the HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="submit()" value="submit contact"/>
```

to

```
<input type="button" onclick="sendForm()" value="submit contact"/>
```

Javascript:

```
function sendForm() {
    $.post('http://************/requestform.php', {

    FirstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
    LastName: $('#LastName').val(),
    Email: $('#Email').val(),
    MessageText: $('#MessageText').val()

    }, function (html) {
         var response=html;

         if (response=="success") {
           alert("Message sent!"); 
         } else {
           alert("Sorry please fill all fields!");
         }
   });

}
```

**Also** see the change
`$("form").submit(function(){`
`$("form1").submit(function(){`
because the form id is `#form1`.

Comment: Sorry, I had already changed that, my mistake for posting that incorrect version, I was still having no joy using POST.

Comment: why you are calling the function `submit()` on button click?

Comment: Thanks for your time, unfortunately neither of these seemed to fix the problem... the submit button does nothing

Comment: Yes because of the `event.preventDefault();`. And why are you calling the function `submit()` on button click?

Comment: The submit button doesn't work at all without the submit(), with on click submit the form empties, however no email is sent and no alert of success is triggered.

Comment: You access the form with `$("form")` but the id of the form is `$("form1")` ..see my edit ..

Comment: I've done everything you asked, however there is still no alert and no email coming through whenever I place $.post(.. inside of any other function.